# Properly type the string arrayiffy function

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to set proper types to an `arrayiffy` function. It's API is the following:

- if a non-empty string is given, it puts it into an array and returns that
- if an empty string is given, it returns an empty array
- if anything else is given, it's returned as-is

The basic type signature overloading works but "any" is not optimal:

```js
function arrayiffy(something: string): [string];
function arrayiffy(something: string): [];
function arrayiffy(something: any): any {
  if (typeof something === "string") {
    if (something.length) {
      return [something];
    }
    return [];
  }
  return something;
}
```

I tried to set up generics but it fails ([TS playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAcg9gOwMrAE4EsEHMA8AVAPigF4o8oIAPYCBAEwGcoG1MsoB+KBCANwlRQAXGQDcAKHEAzAK4IAxsHSIoAQ1SpVIdFKkgAFAzgBbCMAAWbESwzYAlCIDaNtgF0JshUpXrN23QZGphZWzKz2Tu7ScorKCGoaWjp6+OAQBIYmZpbYIvDI4bh4aQQOZGlQAN7iUFA6UPqgkHBSzFkh2CTEpABELtg9dlU1tXWtmcE5WAB0ADa0WBZD1aOjqGYyqPHO7VNRqwC+I7XrwJvb+1BHJxtbbZNsEkdAA)):

```js
type NonString<T> = T extends string ? never : T;

function arrayiffy(something: string): [string];
function arrayiffy(something: string): [];
function arrayiffy<Type>(something: NonString<Type>): Type {
  if (typeof something === "string") {
    if (something.length) {
      return [something];
    }
    return [];
  }
  return something;
}
```

How would you approach this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type StringInABox<T> =
  T extends '' ? [] :
  string extends T ? [] | [string] :
  T extends string ? [T] :
  T;

function arrayiffy<T>(something: T): StringInABox<T>;
function arrayiffy<T>(something: T): [] | [string] | T {
  if (typeof something !== 'string') return something;
  if (something.length) return [something];
  return [];
}
```

[See in Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=22&pln=3&pc=37#code/C4TwDgpgBAysBOBLAdgcwJLIIICED2AHgDwAqAfFALwCwAUFFCVBAcBMgCYDOUA5L1AD8UANoBdKAC46DLghSpmrdt0ZDREgD6i5SNBOn01LNpx66F6kSQMzGAbjp0AZgFdkAY2CI8yKAEN4eH8QRGdnEFIyAAouPABbCGAACwVJRgBKdLg9DGx8YnJHWjdPb18AoJCwiKjYhKTUtHSSLI0obRELfQ61AG87MKho0Eg8Zyg4xJTLAEJKSj5u1F4MqHgk13g-KcaFYoYh+umm1AA6ABt2VBS1jeAtvy6Gmf0D9c3tjWKAXydaaIjdLLNriXpdeQ9SgUQLBULhEAjDIZYqA4DpXhsOSrdIiTEQbESaGVOE1RHAZGooF8HHtYmw6oIpEouho9IAFgATG0uVQYVV4RFmVT0XwscABNouaD8YTerz6QKycKgA)

The `function arrayiffy<T>(something: T): [] | [string] | T` signature only says that you will get one of these three things, `[]` or `[string]` or `T`. It doesn’t specify *when* you’ll get each, and also if you pass in a known string value, it doesn’t indicate that the value you passed in will be the string you find inside the array. Still, this is a relatively type-safe way to write the signature of this function—loads better than `(something: any) => any`.

The overload signature, `arrayiffy<T>(something: T): StringInABox<T>`, does make the guarantees that the other signature was missing. The `StringInABox` conditional type checks for a known-to-be-empty string, an unknown `string` that may or may not be empty (and so the return value is `[] | [string]`), a known-and-not-empty `string` that is put directly into the array (`[T]`), or anything else, which just returns itself.

It’s worth noting that `string extends T` isn’t perfect—if you have a `string & SomethingElse`, it will fail, and move on to the `T extends string`, which will pass. The result is `[string & SomethingElse]`, which could be wrong if the `string` part of the object has the runtime value `''` (if it is known at compile time as `'' & SomethingElse`, then no problem, that will fall in the `T extends ''` bucket).

We use this overload because Typescript doesn’t narrow down conditional types (e.g. `StringInABox<T>`) based on the runtime checks we use on values of the input type (here, `T`). That means that even though we know, and Typescript knows, that `something` is, say, a `string`, Typescript *doesn’t* know that `T` is `string`. As far as Typescript is concerned, `T` is still anything even though we figured out what `something` is. And that means it can’t verify that `[something]` is a valid `StringInABox<T>`, and throws an error. Either we cast all of our return values, or we use an overload. I chose an overload as it’s cleaner-looking, but there’s an argument to be made that it’s better to be ugly and explicit when casting (and that’s effectively what an overload is in TS).

Comment: `string extends T ? [] | [string]` Very nice. This was the part I was stuck on in my in progress answer. This is how to know the string is non empty, if that _can_ be known.

Comment: @AlexWayne You may be interested in the warning I just edited into the answer about that.